G.P. geometry relation
By means of a single geometrical diagram, can you show why a geometrical progression is called a geometrical progression?
I have thought about showing consecutive diagrams of square areas to either show increase or decrease. (We can also use volumes)
We can also relate it with area of total figure as sum of g.p.
I may be totally wrong to understand the question...
In short I tried to show numbers in g.p. as some other form, but is it actually the thing asked in the question, like what is the meaning of the question.

Progressions with a common ratio govern some nested polygon structures. Below is such a structure involving triangles.

Start with $\triangle ABC$. Along ray $\overset{\rightarrow}{AB}$ identify point $B'$ such that $\angle ACB'$ is congruent with $\angle ABC$, and construct line segment $\overline{CB'}$. Then along ray $\overset{\rightarrow}{AC}$ identify point $C'$ such that $\angle AB'C'$ is congruent with $\angle ACB'$, and construct line segment $\overline{B'C'}$. Iterating this process gives a series of triangles in which the areas and the lengths if the sides follow "geometric" progressions.

Ok, nice, got it, thanks.

Just thought of it, We can also use golden spiral, right?

That could work, but we can make sirals with other characteridtic ratios as well. Nothing is really particukar about the golden ratio here.

Yes @oscarlanzi , I meant a different approach, not that specific spiral.
